# Form becomes unresponsive on scale

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a form that acts as a calculator on submit. Everything works fine while I have a large (almost full screen) window with the page open. However, as soon as I scale the window to about half its size, the form fields are no longer selectable or editable objects. Does anyone know why this is happening? Code for the form is posted below. If you need the CSS/Bootstrap files I am using Bootswatch superhero.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header" id="banner">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-sm-6">
                <h1>Reagent Calculator</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <form id="CalcI" onsubmit="return false">
                <legend>Feed me your information</legend>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                <label for="number" pattern="\d*">Volume of DNA</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="volumeDNA" placeholder="&mu;l of DNA" step="any" autocomplete="off">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
                    <label for="number" pattern="\d*">Concentration</label>
                    <input type="number"  class="form-control" id="concentration" placeholder="UNITS HERE" step="any" autocomplete="off">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
                    <label for="number" pattern="\d*">Base Pairs per Fragment</label>
                    <input type="number"  class="form-control" id="BPperFrag" placeholder="BP/Frag DNA" step="any" autocomplete="off">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <button href="#" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Clear</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="Calculate_Pmole();">Calculate</button>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-1">
            <!-- CALCULATOR OUTPUT HERE -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: (fiddle would be useful)

Comment: I've encountered this problem before and it has to do with bootstrap's scaffolding. When making a "contact us" form in the past, the form would work (on full screen) if I made the container a "col-lg-12" but not if I tried to shrink it down (for space requirements) to a "col-lg-6". Same exact code I would use, but just a bootsrap scaffolding issue. Overcame this by messing with the design of my form though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the three `<div>`s containing the editable fields in a `.row`, otherwise the following larger div ends up covering them.

In essence:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-xs-4">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12">
    ...
</div>
```

Working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ge3cve5u/1/).

Comment: Wow thanks for this info, never thought that was the reason before

Comment: @Justin I'm not sure it's exactly the reason, but it's certainly a reasonable workaround

Comment: There currently is a row element around the the form as a whole. I tried moving the `<div class="col-lg-12>` tag below the `row`, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: @David.Sparky if you look at the link to the js fiddle I posted, it shows exactly where the additional row div should be placed

Comment: Update added another `row`. It works now. Thanks for the help! :D